How do I make a sedentary culture more adventurous or exploratory?
In a fantasy society with medieval tech, I want to prevent a situation where the average person has never traveled far from home. My people should have more interaction with other cultures and more experiences visiting different places. I want adventure to be woven into the culture.
By sedentary I mean the phase of development in which most people grow their own food and have a primary home.
How would I do this?

Even in modern times IRL, the average human being has never traveled far from home. Many many people alive today (I would estimate easily more than half of the adult population of the planet) have never traveled more than 50 miles away from the place they grew up. And even among those who have, it’s not unusual for that to be a one-way trip that they never repeat, or for it to be a recurring trip to a specific place with little exposure elsewhere.

Does it need to be the good kind of adventure? Several historical empires used the practice of deporting basically everyone as a way to break up resistance.

This society needs a way to travel. If by land, rivers need easy fords or bridges. At one time, building a bridge was something that wealthy people did for their community. Today, a freeway cutting through a community will divide it.

Traditionally, you have a wizard posts a sign on one of the doors advertising the services of a burglar.

Has there ever been a fantasy society without Medieval tech?

@RonJohn A medieval base for a fantasy setting is very common, but not exclusive. For example, it’s not unusual in high fantasy (especially in Japanese isekai stories) for emulation of much higher tech levels through use of magic, and it’s similarly not that unusual for a lower tech level to be used as a base. It’s just that the stories most people think of as fantasy are very traditional western fantasy inspired by things like Arthurian or Carolingian legend.

Medieval tech is an incredibly vague concept. Usually it just means "somewhere between ancient and modern"

"In a fantasy society with medieval tech, I want to prevent a situation where the average person has never traveled far from home. My people should have more interaction with other cultures and more experiences visiting different places. I want adventure to be woven into the culture."
There is no way to avoid having the average person never travel far from home, because in a society with medieval technology travel is very expensive. Roads are technology. Ships are technology. Coaches are technology. And horses and camels have always been expensive.
This being said, here are some real-world historical examples of medieval societies which had plenty of interaction with other cultures and where a considerable number of people got to see foreign countries and interact with foreign people; I don't know if they perceived themselves as adventurers, but we do so think of them.
So, in historical order:

The centuries long neverending Roman-Persian wars extended to the 7th century, well into the early Middle Ages, and were only ended when the Arabs conquered Persia and a large part of the (Eastern) Roman Empire. Lots of Greeks-who-called-themselves-Romans got to see Persia or at least interact with Persians, and lots of Persians got to see Roman lands or at least interact with Greeks-who-called-themselves-Romans.

In the 5th and the 6th centuries the Angles, the Saxons and the Jutes travelled en masse to Britannia, interacted so to say with the local Celts and Romano-Britons, took over the country and established a new culture.

In the 6th century the (Eastern) Roman emperor Justinian decided to make one last attempt to re-unify the Empire, and had his generals Belisarius and Narses go reconquer Italy and part of North Africa. Lots of Greeks-who-called-themselves-Romans got to see foreign lands and interact with Vandals, Berbers and actual Romans.

In the 7th and 8th centuries the Arabs got bit by the wanderlust bug, exploded out of Arabia, interacted with the Persians, the (Eastern) Roman Empire, the Vandals, the Berbers, and the Visigoths, conquered Persia, Egypt, Syria, Palestine, Lebanon, all of northern Africa, and most of the Iberian Peninsula.

In the 9th and 10th centuries the Norsemen came closest to the desired ideal of a medieval society where adventure is a normal way of life. Lots and lots of them went a-viking at least at some stage in life, interacted with just about all the peoples in Europe and the environs, and got to see just about all European foreign lands accessible by sea, or at least by river; from Ireland and Britain in the west to Russia and Constantinople in the east to Sicily in the south. To mention only two of their enduring legacies, Kievan Russia was founded by Norsemen and the Norsemen acquired Normandy from the King of France.

In the 11th century lots and lots of people in western Europe and went to conquer Palestine and bits of Lebanon and Syria. Why on Earth would people leave well-watered and fertile England and Germany and France and travel thousands of miles in order to interact with the Arabs and fight deadly battles for the almost-deserts of the Near East is a mystery and a testament to the abysmal state of geographical knowledge in the Middle Ages.

Throughout the Middle Ages the Genoese and Venetian Republics were great commercial and maritime powers, traded with everybody around the Mediterranean, established far-flung colonies and extended their dominion over foreign lands. Even here in Romania we have a few cities which were originally founded as Genoese colonies. Venice ruled Crete from the 13th to the 17th century!

And finally, in 1492 the Most Catholic Monarchs Ferdinand and Isabella of Spain had a brainwave and ordered all the Jews in their kingdom to leave or stop being Jews. Tens of thousands of Sephardic Jews embarked on a great adventure, albeit not by choice, travelling to farway foreign countries, interacting with the locals, and establishing new lives from the Low Countries to Constantinople.



The Crusades were no mystery.  The Central European nations did not invade Palestine because of land or greed, it was a counter offensive against the Muslim Jihad.  Muslims had for centuries been invading Christian lands with the goal of eradicating Christianity.  Every time they either took more Christian land or they were repelled only to regroup and try again later, but after about ~300 years of this, it became clear across all of Europe that the Muslims would eventually win unless Christianity started taking lands right back.

So, the crusades were no different than Ukraine taking Kursk from Russia.  The goal was not what could be gained, it was to bring the war to the enemy's land to try to break their will to keep fighting

@Nosajimiki: ??? Wrong Muslims. You know, the Muslims had several different states with different rulers and different interests, just like the Christians. The Fatimids who ruled over Palestine were definitely not invading any European lands. It would have been like the USA attacking Iraq after 9/11. Oh wait, the USA did attack Iraq! And note that the crusaders did not even attempt to attack the Almoravids who were actually lording over the southern half of the Iberian Peninsula, right there in Europe. P.S. It was mostly a Western European thing, not a Central European thing.

Yes, but the "first" Crusade was not the beginning of the counterattack.  When the Caliphate of Córdoba fell apart, the remaining Muslim taifas in Spain were easy pickings for Portugal, León-Castile, and Aragon in a series of conquests called the Reconquista. Shortly thereafter, the Muslims also lost a lot of ground in Sicily, Southern Italy, and Tunisia to Norman warlords who decided to bypass all sorts of closer, more easily conquered Christian kingdoms to strike at the Muslim threat that was getting dangerously close to the Vatican.

This was Northern Europe's first clear act of going out of their way to target Muslim lands on the behalf of the Papacy.  Then a few years later the Byzantine Empire started doing very poorly, against the Seljuk Turks.  So, the First Crusade was actually a second Papal call to arms for Northern Europe and was supposed to mimic what the Normans did to push the Muslims back out of Italy, but in this case, it was to push them back out of Palestine.

So, if you want to be specific, it was the Seljuk Turks invasion of Byzantium that prompted the first Crusade, but the Crusaders did not differentiate between the Fatimids and the Turks since both were Muslim nations that held lands that were recently taken from Byzantium.

@AlexP Syria, Lebanon, large chunks of Palestine, even Egypt were all majority Christian before before Islam was a religion. Islam spread fast, and far, by the sword... And modern  history teachers do a really good job of glossing over Islam's bloody history. They weren't the victims of christian religious zeal. It is a lot more complicated  than that.

Pilgrimage
Everyone travels (at least) once in their life, if they can, to visit the Great Cathedral in the Holy City (or whatever).  Or maybe to the Font of Magic, to be tested for their magical aptitude, when they are on the cusp of adulthood.  Most don't travel regularly (you've got to tend the farm, the home business, what have you), but it's unusual to not have made that one particular trip.
There's a great deal of latitude, in a fantasy setting, for what exactly it is that people have a very strong motivation to go to visit - but you can declare that (most) people do indeed go.

Note that to increase exploration, this "pilgrimage" might not involve a fixed target, but rather something like "find magical creature X", or "follow the wind for 20 days".

... or it is a floating island.  That way, it is both a "holy land" and an unfixed target

A Muslim who has made the pilgrimage to Mecca is known as a "Haji", and that conveys status. So give each returned pilgrim a title, maybe the right to wear a distinguished item of clothing, and the right to be listened to, with respect, at village assemblies. The guy or gal has survived a dangerous journey, and so has probably learned something.

@Nosajimiki Ooh, I like the idea of it being a floating island, not a fixed destination.

Like the Amish
First of all let's get one thing out if the way. You can only have adventures as a culture if your home is in order. You need to have a steady supply if resources, or else people will either stay at home to help or migrate. It could be that they import stuff, but it would be difficult to do for a whole culture.
I once have read that the Amish have a period starting at adolescence where the new adolescent can make a choice. They are allowed to rebel after a fashion, and can even go out and experience the world and modern technology, with the option to return later and join the community again. They can go on adventures.
Now I actually read up on it, it seems to be much more restrictive and nuanced. It is still a basis which we can alter to your stories needs. As the culture is affluent in resources the extra labour is not valued as much as the experience of them going 'on an adventure'. They are actively supported to go out into the world, possibly in groups or with a sort of sherpa. When they return they might have partners, gained riches or lost people close to them. They come back experienced, an adolescent with worldly knowledge and experience. A member that can truly strengthen the community.
Whatever has happened the adolescents are welcomed back with open arms, strengthening the bonds of the culture. A shared experience that knits them together, allowing them to be sedentary with an adventurous streak.

Many local (Czech) folk tales start with a young boy leaving the home "to gain experience", which meant traveling a bit and get some odd/seasonal jobs elsewhere. This was often reserved for second+ sons who didn't inherit the farm. I am not sure how old the practice is (the tales were usually written down in 18th/19th century, so mostly pre-industrial, but not necessarily medieval)


How do I make a sedentary culture more adventurous or exploratory?

There are at least two ways to take sedentary here.

: not migratory : settled
sedentary birds
sedentary civilizations
merriam-webster.com - sedentary

Taken that way this is an oxymoron. The more you get what you want the less the culture is sedentary.

a : doing or requiring much sitting
    a sedentary job
b : not physically active
    a sedentary lifestyle
merriam-webster.com - sedentary

Taken that way...
So you want to go somewhere, but you want to sit. I have just the thing:


scmp.com - Sedan chairs vs sedans

All you need now is to see the person in the chair as an "average person" and the ones under the polls as "non-persons". Which was a typical medieval attitude. At least among average persons.

Scale up the concept of Journeyman Years
In the past, craftsman apprentices used to have "journeyman years" , where basically after their master taught them enough of what HE knows, they'd go out into the world and see how other people do it. Wikipedia Link
If your society is secure enough in their food supplies to afford sending out a farmer's children for a year or five too (instead of having them continuously help on the farm), this could be a tradition in your culture for all people: learn what you can from your parents/master/whatnot, then travel for X years seeing how your job is done in other places. Return home with that knowledge to make your home better, or settle where you found a beautiful partner bringing your own knowledge from home to that place.

Perhaps they are colonizing a huge, empty continent and, and in every next generation one third of the population just goes upcontinent in search for more lands.
They are adventurous and exploratory because their fathers or grandfathers were adventurous and exploratory and that's how they came to live where they live. Otherwise, they still live sedentiary life with wheat/rice/corn farming, veggies and some dairy/lamb.
The land is essentially empty because they are outcompeting and assimilating local nomads, which happen to have way less population density and can no longer compete militarily against a centralized state with pikes, swords and early muskets.
Kind of Russia in the XVI-XVIII centuries, or USA in XIX century but with medieval level of development.

Make it a Trade Empire
Throughout history, some economies have tried very hard to be fully self-sufficient keeping trade and travel to a bare minimum, some have purposefully specialized their production with the intention of trading what they are good at making for everything else they need, and some have gone even further by making the act of trade itself the product that they specialize in.  To make a medieval civilization want to get out into the world and travel, you need it to be in this third category of economy.
In the late 20th century we saw a boom in civilizations moving towards this 2nd and 3rd category as part of the globalization movement; so, a lot of people think that this is an exclusively modern thing, but it is not.  Trade cultures go back to the very beginning of recorded history where the Phoenicians developed a whole culture around exploration and trade; so, using technology far less advanced than what you see in the medieval period, they traveled all throughout Europe, Africa, and the Middle East establishing trade routes, not just from the World to Phoenicia, but between other nations as well.
Why were trade cultures so rare in the Medieval Period
It was a political issue, not a technological one.  The Feudal system tied a person's sense of value and self-worth to the land they owned.  Economic power was in many ways secondary to the political power that land ownership offered.  If you owned 100 acres of good farmland, you could bring in 20 tenants to work your land.  They would do all the work and pay you a rent/tax and you would have a passive income, authoritarian rulership over them, and the protection of 20 men at your command.  It was such a good deal to be a landowner, that any reasonable person who gathered the wealth to either acquire a tradeship or more land would choose more land nearly every time.  Furthermore, Europe had a strict caste system based on landownership and not wealth.  So, even if you could make a lot of money with a fleet of tradeships, if that money does not lead to land ownership, you may still just be a commoner in the eyes of society.
... but they did exist
That said, even in this dark age of trade, there was one major nexus of trade culture in Medieval Europe located in Northern Italy. Instead of pure feudalism, this region was ruled following a model more closely resembling ancient Greek City States.  In Venice for example, they had a special council called Consiglio dei Rogati which was a trade council that eventually grew to take on the roll of a legislative Senate, and in Florence and Genoa, they had a Capitano del Popolo who was an elected leader that the trade guilds appointed to rule over the nobility and keep them in check.  As such, these places offered not just money, but political power and respect to their merchant class; so, they viewed travel very differently than the rest of Europe. To a Northern Italian, leaving your home to travel the world was no longer seen as abandoning your home to become a worthless vagabond, it was an opportunity to rise up in station and become something more and better than a simple farmer. This simple change in culture and politics encouraged young Italians to study foreign languages and maps and to plan their lives around traveling far and wide, because this became the respectable thing to do.
So if you want your fantasy culture to be well travelled, I'd suggest basing it on the Northern Italian Medieval culture as opposed to the more strict Feudalistic cultures of somewhere like France or England.

for that to work, the Fantasy Culture Realm needs to be located in a place with poor farmland but a lot of islands, peninsulas, bays and rivers, preferably with the most of their borders being with a "merchant friendly" sea, like the Mediterranean or the Baltic. You need to constrict their choice so they HAVE TO pick a sail over a plow if they want to prosper.

Go do good deeds for neighboring countries.
It needs to become part of the ethos to perform good deeds. This will need to be done in a deliberate way, sending parties (it's a great honor to be chosen to be invited) into nearby countries to help them with infrastructure - well-digging, clearing of agricultural land, helping in times of famine to distribute food/medicaments and tend to the sick - even fighting the odd skirmish.
This can be on a religious or secular basis, the justifications are just couched differently - but the upshot is the same - people get to travel, relations with neighbors is improved.
Scribes, artists, players (the theatre type, not poker) and bards should all be encouraged to sample the varied cultures and create great works of art, spread foreign songs (eg. in our idiom Frère Jacques, 99 Luftballons, Shikdum etc..) - and give them ours if they're interested.
Games would be organized  between municipalities (counties/states) and a league would be drawn up. Top teams of participating countries would compete and audiences from all over would be encouraged to migrate to the arenas temporarily.
Groups of religions would be brought together to debate the "big questions" in a civilized and respectful way and to swap tails of converts and communities. Priests from far abroad would be asked to tell their stories of enlightenment and parables of caution to audiences from all over. Stories would be taken down by scribes and repeated from time to time.
Exchange visits could be organized for the neighbors to visit your country too - even if only in grape-picking season to help with the harvest. These would be put-up by locals who'd be provided with sufficient resources to look after them so as to not hamper survival.
Children would be encouraged to go stay with neighbors and learn their language - again, some resources will need to be spent to accomplish this without causing severe resentment/hardship in the host family.
This will cost the crown/government a great deal of money - but not as much as fighting full-scale war.
Full scale war.
Supply chains and ancillary work would be the norm for many, and on the front line there's be the soldiers - not far behind the medical and supply-line distribution - with front's constantly shifting and cooperation/antagonism
of the locals essential - there's sure to be cultural mixing. This would be by far the more expensive option in gold and in lives.
Your allies would send you reinforcements to live in your country in digs (again, supplies need to be provided to avoid hardship).

In Medieval time travel is a risk, and most people are bound to the land to produce food and resources needed to survive. Your only way to make what you want is to make the economy of the homeland harsh and poor, so harsh and poor that the only valuable thing one has is their body.
This will make so most of the people tired of breaking their back for stale bread and an onion will embark for the world as mercenaries, either for war or love.
Notable historical example: Swiss mercenaries and Landsknecht.

So there are plenty of real world examples of tribes/villages which have grand fairs with others to meetup for trade and culture.
The Champagne Fairs were huge and attracted visitors from much of Europe. You could have similar fairs and tournaments.
There are also cultural examples where you have clans which predominantely marry outside the clan so at cultural meetings with other clans. Exogamy has been theorised to have come about strongly is some cultures due to initially high amounts of Bride Kidnapping / Marriage by Capture and then developed as a custom.
So reasons for travel for fairs, and for marriage are good ways to encourage travel amongst much of a populace.
To also encourage travel could happen by travel being easier, fantastical approaches by magical beasts of burden, or portals. Or more realistic ones like well used trade-routes having regular carriages for transporting people, or like Mongols having a horse-riding culture makes travel more accessible for most people.
I'd say making your specific group of people have access to fast travel (i.e. horses) and a culture of Exogamy would encourage people to travel around and interact with other cultures.

Increase the availability of riding beasts, horses or whatever your setting has. If everyone who wants one can have a horse, they will be better able to travel farther compared to just walking.
If you can find a way to make growing their own food take less time and effort, all the better.

or just cut the land with a million of rivers, big and small, so that people could float downriver on boats and rafts, and paddle or sail upriver.
